# How to update whose status is 0 to 1?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get all the user whose status is 0 and then update them to 1.

```js
public function notification ()
{
  $data = Ghar::where('status',0)->get();
  foreach($data as $dat)
  {
    $id = $dat->id;
    $aa['status'] = '1';
    if(Ghar::find($id)->update($aa))
    {
      print_r('ok');
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery or AJAX? I've removed those tags

Comment: So what's wrong? And I don't think you need to get all data and loop it. In plain SQL: `UPDATE ghar SET status = 1 WHERE status = 0`

Comment: I didn't find jquery anywhere. Please don't contaminate tags

Answer (score 1):

All these (same) answers can be narrowed down to:

```
$data = Ghar::whereStatus(0)->update(['status' => 1]);
```

*Note: This doesn't trigger the update/save events as it is a mass update.*

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public function notification ()
{
    $data = Ghar::where('status',0)->get();
    foreach($data as $dat)
    {
        $dat->status = 1;
        $dat->save();
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you you have only getting data whose status is `0` and you want to set it to `1` which you can do simply by trying below code

```
public function notification ()
{
    $data = Ghar::where('status',0)->get();
    foreach($data as $dat)
    {
         // $dat is already a object of Ghar model so you don't need call find here you can simply do this
         $dat->update(['status' => 1]);
    }
}
```

Thanks